# Regular expression to parse useragent string

Tags: php, regex

I need extract data from a string. Heres an example:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS
>   X; tr-tr) AppleWebKit/418 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Safari/417.9.3

I want to get what's after the "Safari/" (417.9.3) **but**:

1. The "Safari" string can be in any character case and can be anywhaere in the string.
2. The version is separated from "Safari" by "/", " /", "/ ", " / " or any whitespace.
3. The version string end by any whitespace, ")", "(", ";", or the end of the string.

Anyone can help me build this up?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with PHP:s `get_browser`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_match("#Safari(\s+|/\s*)([^)(;]+)#i", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $results);
```

The `i` at the end means "case insensitive", which answers criteria one.

`(\s+|\s*/\s*)?` matches either at least one whitespace character or a slash preceded and followed by an arbitrary number of whitespace characters (from zero to infinity and beyond), which addresses criteria two.

`[^)(;]+` will match as many characters as possible that are *not* inside the set, which addresses criteria three.

Comment: For "(Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/412 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/412 Privoxy/3.0" your regex don't stop on the space. Why?

Comment: @Activist: because I forgot to put `\s` inside the last set (`[^();\s]+` instead of `[^();]+`). Besides, you should try to learn regular expressions. That's one really easy fix you could have done yourself if you learned how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this similar to the Firefox regex that you asked for before?

```
/Safari[ \/]+([0-9\.]+)/i
```